# How to explain the difference between stealing the design and copying the design?

Tags: website-design, copyright, website-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does inspiration end, where does illegitimate copying start?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3303/where-does-inspiration-end-where-does-illegitimate-copying-start)

How to explain the difference between stealing the design and copying the design? In Web Designs. How do you take inspiration from others design without stealing it?

Comment: The difference between *stealing* and *copying* is mostly semantic.  The difference between *copying* and *drawing-inspiration-from* is [well described by Lauren Ipsum on a very similar question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3303/where-does-inspiration-end-where-does-illegitimate-copying-start/3304#3304)

Comment: My question was different

Comment: Can you edit your question to add more clarity?  I'm sure Philip wouldn't mind reopening the question if it could be made noticeably different from the previous question.  As it stands now, the only difference I see is that it is asking specifically the difference between "copying" and "stealing", which is really a discussion about words and not design.

Comment: Related discussion about the ethics of copying: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/is-it-ethical-to-copy-the-work-of-other-designers/